# how helpers.translate('SOME_KEY') works?

Tags: selenium, protractor, angular-translate, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am wondering that how **helpers.translate('SOME_KEY');** works in protractor?

i am using it like:

```
expect(element(by.css('.contact_tag')).getText()).toEqual('CONTACT');
```

here 'CONTACT' string translated in English as 'contact details'. i am getting the following output

output:

```
Expected 'contact details' to equal Object({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }), catch: Object({  }), finally: Object({  }), then: Object({  }) }).
```

somebody please explain me that how this helpers.translate works? from where it takes this CONTACT translate string?